# How can I set NeoTree to always show hidden files?

Tags: init-file, neotree

The only way i know to make NeoTree show hidden files is to use [`neotree-hidden-file-toggle`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NeoTree#toc6), but this is meant to be used interactively when the NeoTree buffer is the active buffer. Is there a way to globally set in my `.emacs` init file to make NeoTree always have the behavior of showing hidden files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found here: https://github.com/jaypei/emacs-neotree/issues/117#issuecomment-126751086

add `(setq-default neo-show-hidden-files t)` to your init.el.

Just in case you use Spacemacs:
add `'(neo-show-hidden-files t)` in `custom-set-variables` of your .spacemacs file.

Comment: When a variable is global (like `neo-show-hidden-files`), `setq` is sufficient.  `setq-default` is generally used for things like `buffer-local` variables where a user wishes to start with a particular default value which may or may not be set differently in certain buffers.  Using `setq-default` in an answer leads the reader to believe that the variable is `buffer-local`, which is not the case here.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you rounding out the answer. However, I actually do want to be able to set this differently in different NeoTree buffers, so only setting the initial default buffer behavior is correct. Thus the answer is best suited to my needs, even though my question doesn't indicate the need for such flexibility.

Comment: @eestrada -- Making a global variable capable of buffer local settings is normally achieved by adding `(make-variable-buffer-local 'neo-show-hidden-files)` and then it can be set locally in any buffer using `setq`.  However, it is possible to use `setq-local` to make a global variable local in a current buffer.  There are a few other methods to take a global variable and use it locally ...

Comment: Shouldn't the instructions for spacemacs say the same thing, that is to use `t` instead of `nil`?

Comment: @JurajMartinka you are correct. I don't know what i was thinking back then. I updated the answer. Thanks!